# Why would I suddenly get 'KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to user@REALM' errors?

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

We've been using Kerberos auth with several (older) Cloudera instances without a problem but now are now getting 'KerberosName$NoMatchingRule: No rules applied to user@REALM' errors. We've been modifying code to add functionality but AFAIK nobody has touched either the authentication code or the cluster configuration.

(I can't rule it out - and clearly SOMETHING has changed.)

I've set up a simple unit test and verified this behavior. At the command line I can execute 'kinit -kt user.keytab user' and get the corresponding Kerberos tickets. That verifies the correct configuration and keytab file.

However my standalone app fails with the error mentioned.

UPDATE

As I edit this I've been running the test in the debugger so I can track down exactly where the test is failing and it seems to be succeed when run in the debugger!!! Obviously there's something different in the environments, not some weird heisenbug that is only triggered when nobody is looking.

I'll update this if I find the cause. Does anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Search about `core-site.xml` property `auth_to_local` and about the command-line to test how Kerberos principals are mapped to Linux users. Maybe you've got a regression in conf files. Maybe you've got random upper/lowercase mismatches (Active Directory is case insensitive, for instance, but the Hadoop rules are not by default...)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't explain why it had been working, stopped working, then resumed working without a change to the conf file. I can't rule out a change when it stopped working but definitely didn't make any changes when it started working again.

Comment: Did you check in the logs which specific NameNodes and/or DataNodes would behave OK or KO? The perverse thing about Cloudera switching & restarting & reswitching NN when they fail canary tests is that you can easily overlook the fact you have a "bad" node...

Comment: I am getting this too now.  Did you ever come up with an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Auth_to_local has to have at least one rule.

Make sure you have “DEFAULT” rule at the very end of auth_to_local.

If none rules before match, at least DEAFULT rule would kick in.

Comment: See comment above - the behavior changed without me touching conf files. On this specific point I verified that auth_to_local was set to DEFAULT early on. Thx.

Comment: Do you have cross-domain authentication? Did your admins changed anything in the AD domains? (assuming you're using AD for Kerberos). Separately, is your client application Talend? We've seen something weird with exactly like this error in Talend jobs and it seems was client-specific. On a separate note, check https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/Connect-to-secure-hadoop-cluster-from-non-cluster-host/td-p/35470 . Finally, here's where error happens - https://github.com/hanborq/hadoop/blob/master/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/security/KerberosName.java#L399 if this helps